# Adding enum values to a list inside an action

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, action

I have the following code that has a few errors in it that I cant work out. I'm trying to add values to a `List` if the user has access, and then return that `List`.

The red line appears under `notificationsList` when I try and return it.

But I'm not sure if I have done this right to start with.

```
public ActionResult GetUserNotificationOptions() {

    List<NotificationOption> notificationsList = new List<NotificationOption>();

    if(UserAccountHandler.GetIsAuthorised(_db, RestrictedArea.Audits))
    {
        notificationsList.Add(NotificationOption.NewAudits);
    }
    if (UserAccountHandler.GetIsAuthorised(_db, RestrictedArea.Overview))
    {
        notificationsList.Add(NotificationOption.SiginificentDeviationInScore);
    }
    if (UserAccountHandler.GetIsAuthorised(_db, RestrictedArea.Action))
    {
        notificationsList.Add(NotificationOption.OutstandingActions);
    }

    return notificationsList;
}
```

Comment: change to return Ok(notificationsList);

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a type mismatch to me. My C# is rusty, but it looks like your method declares that it returns an `ActionResult`, but actually returns a `List<NotificationOption>`.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Declare the class to return a the List using `public class List<NotificationOption> GetUserNotificationOptions{}`

or

2. Convert your list to an `ActionResult` before returning it.

Comment: Yes thank you both, you are right its not an action but a public list.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function as :

```
public List<NotificationOption> GetUserNotificationOptions() {
```

otherwise the return variable is incompatible with the declared return type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the result to the client you can use `JsonResult` as one possible option.

```
public JsonResult GetUserNotificationOptions() {

    ...
    return Json(notificationsList);

}
```